# How to get an XML string in a java file?

Tags: java, android, xml

So, right now i have a text element in my XML file that asks for user input, how do i get this user input into my java file so i can use it there as a number?This is my XML so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/uitgaven"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/uitgaven"
     />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/inkomsten"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/inkomsten"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

My java is basically empty at the moment since i don't know that much about it at the moment.

Comment: Seriously, please read a tutorial. It'll do a lot to ease the learning phase, especially at such very beginner cases..

Comment: `EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uirgaven); et1.getText().toStrting();`

Answer (score 0):

First you must get the view using

`mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uitgaven)`

or

`mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inkomsten)`

Whichever one you need the text for. Then all you need to do is get the text itself. You can get that by

```
String myText = mEditText.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the EditText view using ID

```
  EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.uitgaven);
  EditText editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inkomsten);
```

Next get the value specified in the view

```
String value,value1 = null;
value=editText.getText().toString();
value1=editText1.getText().toString();
```